# Not able to open the JqueryUI Dialog Again and again

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

this the jqueryUI

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,modal: true,
show: {
effect: "bounce",
duration: 1000
},
hide: {
effect: "fade",
duration: 1000
},
open: function ()
            {
                $(this).load('password.php');
            },
        height: 400,
            width: 400,
            title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page',           
});
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

html

```
<a href="#" id="opener">Open Dialog</a>
<div class="dialog" id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"></div>
```

This work should be , if the password.php only contain text .
however when password.php contain mysql query , can't open dialog again and again ?
no error in console window, but no able open dialog again as previously excepting press F5 / refreshing page.
what the problem ? 
thank

Comment: is there any error in console window ?

Comment: no error in console window, but no able open dialog again as previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add close event handler.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
// your previous code as it is 
 ,close: function( event, ui ) {$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );}      
});
```